# What is an alternative for an iFrame?

Tags: html

My boss just asked me to re-create an old web part. It's basically image tiles that, upon being clicked, dynamically load another page into an iframe on that main page. Something like this:

```
images___________
  [][]|
  [][]|
  [][]|  iframe
      |
      |
```

She doesn't want me to use iFrames. However, the dynamic content must be stored in a separate page and have a separate URL. How can I take separate page content with a URL and load it into my main page without an iFrame?

Comment: Is there a good reason for not using an iFrame?

Comment: Not that I know of. I'm still new to most of the stuff. I was just told not to use it.

Comment: Ask what the reason for not using an iFrame. If its a good reason then you've at least learned something and use some of the suggestions below. If its a bad reason then we'll tell you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jquery.load();](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to perform that. You can try it out and if you run into problems update your question with code and issue and I/somebody can help you.

The basic idea of `load()` looks like this

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  //here you can update a div on your page with content from the file/page
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Ajax and load the content in a div.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is the `<object>` tag, or loading the content with Ajax, then adding it into an html element.